# SOAP constructed by .NET client has valid object, Java client SOAP has null object

Tags: java, .net, soap

I am having trouble with a SOAP constructed under a Java client communicating with a .NET web service. 
I also have a .NET client for testing purposes and with this client i do not have any problem.

Can you help me find what might be wrong?

SOAP JAVA

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Body>
<ns2:exportReferentiel xmlns:ns2="http://www.svad.actoll.com/Svad2BPass/V1.0">
<exportData>
<produit idRechargement="202" libelle="Ticket 10 x 1h individuel" LibelleIhm="Ticket 10x1h ind" ordreTri="10" descriptionLongue="Ticket 10 x 1h individuel" dateDebut="1999-01-01T00:00:00.000+01:00" dateFin="2099-01-01T00:00:00.000+01:00">
    <tarif libelle="202">
    <validiteTarif dateDebut="1999-01-01T00:00:00.000+01:00" dateFin="2099-01-01T00:00:00.000+01:00" valeur="1070" />
    <validiteTarif dateDebut="1999-01-01T00:00:00.000+01:00" dateFin="2099-01-01T00:00:00.000+01:00" valeur="1070" />
    </tarif>
    </produit>
...
```

The above SOAP has a Null Object

.NET SOAP

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <exportReferentiel xmlns="http://www.svad.actoll.com/Svad2BPass/V1.0">
      <exportData>
        <produit idRechargement="998" libelle="Teste" LibelleIhm="Teste" ordreTri="98" descriptionLongue="batatinhas" dateDebut="2010-05-10T00:00:00" dateFin="2012-12-31T00:00:00" xmlns="">
          <tarif libelle="998">
            <validiteTarif dateDebut="2010-05-10T00:00:00" dateFin="2012-12-31T00:00:00" valeur="300" />
            <validiteTarif dateDebut="2012-12-31T23:59:59.999" dateFin="2013-12-31T00:00:00" valeur="600" />
          </tarif>
        </produit>
...
```

Web Service .NET

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://www.svad.actoll.com/Svad2BPass/V1.0")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[ToolboxItem(false)]
public class Service : System.Web.Services.WebService, ISvad2BPass
{
    private static bool Debug = false;
[WebMethod]
    [SoapDocumentMethod("http://www.svad.actoll.com/Svad2BPass/V1.0/exportReferentiel")]
    public ExportPassTransBPassStatusType exportReferentiel(ExportPassTransBPassType exportData)
    {
        Debug = bool.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Debug"]);

        Logger.Instance.Log(LogTypeCode.DEBUG, exportData.ToString());

        exportReferentielRequest req = new exportReferentielRequest(exportData);
        return LoadExportPassTransBPass(req);
    }
```

The exportData with the Java SOAP becomes null, while with the .NET SOAP it becomes alright with all data...

Can anyone help me on this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this by adding the ns2 to the exportData tag. 
So the correct construction of this SOAP is:

```
<ns2:exportReferentiel xmlns:ns2="http://www.svad.actoll.com/Svad2BPass/V1.0">
<ns2:exportData>
 <produit idRechargement="202" libelle="Ticket 10 x 1h individuel" LibelleIhm="Ticket 10x1h ind" ordreTri="10" descriptionLongue="Ticket 10 x 1h individuel" dateDebut="1999-01-01T00:00:00.000+01:00" dateFin="2099-01-01T00:00:00.000+01:00">
  <tarif libelle="202">
   <validiteTarif dateDebut="1999-01-01T00:00:00.000+01:00" dateFin="2099-01-01T00:00:00.000+01:00" valeur="1070" />
   <validiteTarif dateDebut="1999-01-01T00:00:00.000+01:00" dateFin="2099-01-01T00:00:00.000+01:00" valeur="1070" />
  </tarif>
 </produit>
...
</ns2:exportData>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I was fighting a similar problem yesterday.  Finally found that the parameter name in the contract interface didn't match what was being passed by the client.  However looking at your requests I don't see any name differences between the Java client and the .net client.

What does your interface look like?

Comment: [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.svad.actoll.com/Svad2BPass/V1.0", ConfigurationName = "Svad2BPass")]
    public interface ISvad2BPass
    {
[System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action = "http://www.svad.actoll.com/Svad2BPass/V1.0/exportReferentiel", ReplyAction = "*")]
[System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(SupportFaults = true)]
ExportPassTransBPassStatusType exportReferentiel(ExportPassTransBPassType exportData);

Comment: Do you think it is a Interface problem?

Comment: That looks okay to me.  Must be something different from a parameter name mismatch.  Afraid I don't have enough experience to think of what else it could be.

Comment: Hi Jacob, i figured out what was wrong, I posted a response a few hours ago... Thank you

Comment: Didn't you you were able to modify your incoming request. Sorry, I would have offered that.  Glad it's working now.